# Freeing memory when deleting node from BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, delete-operator

I am having difficulty releasing memory for my BST deletion. The algorithm itself works, so long as I don't include the "delete" keyword. As soon as I do, it causes this error: malloc: *** error for object 0x7fec6a4026a0: 
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Here is my code, along with the single "delete" keyword. I've also included other locations where I've tried placing the delete keyword. I understand that you must free up the memory in C++ to prevent memory leaks. I have a feeling that the recursive call may be causing the problem, but I can't pinpoint it.

```
bool AVLTree::deleteNode(string ss, AVLNode* starting){
AVLNode* curr = starting;
AVLNode* parent = starting->parent;

while (curr != nullptr) {
    if (curr->ssn == ss) {
        // Remove leaf
        if (curr->right == nullptr && curr->left == nullptr) {
            // Remove root
            if (parent == nullptr) {
                root = nullptr;
            }
            else if (parent->left == curr) {
                parent->left = nullptr;
            }
            else {
                parent->right = nullptr;
            }
            // IVE TRIED PUTTING DELETE HERE
        }

        // Remove node with two children
        else if (curr->right != nullptr && curr->left != nullptr) {
            // Find succesor
            AVLNode* succ = curr->right;
            while (succ->left != nullptr) {
                succ = succ->left;
            }

            // Copy
            curr->ssn = succ->ssn;
            curr->name = succ->name;

            deleteNode(succ->ssn, curr->right);
        }

        // Remove node with one children
        else {
            // If has left child
            if (curr->left != nullptr) {
                if (parent == nullptr) {
                    root = curr->left;
                }
                else if (parent->left == curr) {
                    parent->left = curr->left;
                }
                else {
                    parent->right = curr->left;
                }
            } 
            else if (curr->right != nullptr) {
                if (parent == nullptr) {
                    root = curr->right;
                }
                else if (parent->left == curr) {
                    parent->left = curr->right;
                }
                else {
                    parent->right = curr->right;
                }
            }
            // IVE TRIED PUTTING DELETE HERE
        }
        delete curr; // THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
        return true;
    }
    else if ((curr->ssn.compare(ss)) < 0) {
        parent = curr;
        curr = curr->right;
    }
    else {
        parent = curr;
        curr = curr->left;
    }
}

return false;
}


 // Insert function
bool AVLTree::insert(string ss, string na){
    AVLNode* curr = root;

    // Construct new AVL Node 
    AVLNode* newNode = new AVLNode(ss, na);

    // If root is empty, insert
    if (curr == nullptr) {
        root = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    while (curr != nullptr) {
        if (curr->ssn.compare(newNode->ssn) == 0) {
            delete newNode;
            return false;
        } 
        // Go right
        if (newNode->ssn.compare(curr->ssn) > 0) {
            // Check to see if we can insert, currs right child is null
            if (curr->right == nullptr) {
                curr->right = newNode;
                newNode->parent = curr;
                break;
            }
            else {
                curr = curr->right;
            }
        } 
        // Go left
        else {
            // Check to see if we can insert
            if (curr->left == nullptr) {
                curr->left = newNode;
                newNode->parent = curr;
                break;
            } else {
                curr = curr->left; 
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `new` when making a node?

Comment: *so long as I don't include the "delete" keyword. As soon as I do, it causes this error* -- Blaming poor old `delete`, when the problem originated elsewhere.  All `delete` is showing you is either 1) you are not issuing the `delete` on a pointer to a buffer allocated with `new`, or 2) your program corrupted memory long ago, and `delete` is just a symptom of the memory corruption.

Comment: @Cuber Yes I am

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I allocate memory using the "new" keyword during the insertion of the node into the BST.

Comment: @DarshanKalola -  Then check the value returned by `new`.  Is it the same value you're using when you issue the `delete`?  Note the keyword is **value**, not pointer.  You can have `new` return a value, and then you mess up the pointer by changing the value, and then issuing a `new` on that pointer, thinking things will work.